# Select from 3 tables where 3 conditions SQL and Codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I'm facing some troubles with a query that i cannot complete, the main problem is that i'm joining 2 tables and adding 2 conditions:

```
SQL Table
Products table:
id,name,section
1,Product 1,Computer
2,Product 2,Computer
3,Product 3,Computer
4,Product 4,Computer

Table1:
id,pr_id,value,qty
1,2,1

Table2:
id,pr_id,value,qty
1,1,2,1
1,2,2,2
1,3,2,3
1,3,3,1
1,3,4,1

$itemsIds = array('1', '2', '3');
$value = 2;
$q = $this->db->select('Ai.id as AiId, Ai.pr_id as AiPrId, Ai.value as AiValueId, Ai.qty as AiQty, AiR.id as AiRId, AiR.pr_id as AiRPrId, AiR.value as AiRValueId, AiR.qty as AiRQty, P.name as pName')
    ->from('products P')
    ->where_in('P.id', $itemsIds)
    ->join('table1 Ai', 'P.id=Ai.pr_id', 'left')
    ->join('table2 AiR', 'P.id=AiR.pr_id', 'left')
    ->where(array('AiValueId' => $value, 'AiRValueId' => $value))
    ->group_by('P.id')
    ->get();
```

The main problem is that with this Conditions im getting only the table 1 values and not the table 2 values too.
My question is how can i get the Table1 and Table2 with the conditions?

Comment: what results are you getting? can you take a snapshot, and place it on your original post?

Comment: What im getting is or Values from Table1 or Values from Table2, what i want is to get the both Table values.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem lies on your where clause. Change this:

```
 ->where(array('AiValueId' => $value, 'AiRValueId' => $value))
```

to this:

```
 ->where('Ai.value', $value)
 ->or_where('AiR.value',$value)
```

Let me know if that works.

Comment: I tried that before, the idea is that the OR condition will take Table1 or Table2, but it will stop on find the items on Table1, what i need is tot check on Table2 too and get the items from Table2 if exists.